# Search word starting with '-', if next word does not start with same pattern then keep it in same line, else move it to new line

Tags: sed, grep, csh

I have a text file which contains bunch of strings as shown below.

```
-V -am line+tgl -am assert -debug+all -zdb -fcs_assert off
```

I want to search for string starting with pattern '-' and check if the next word starts with '-'. If it does then move it to next line, else keep it in the same line.

Expected output:

```
-V
-am sqr+tgl
-am assert
-debug+all
-zdb
-fcs_assert off
```

I tried replacing space with next line character and lines which don't start with '-' append it to  previous line. I am unable to figure out the second half of this approach.

```
cat ins.tmp/cmd.vcs | sed 's/ /\n/g'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```bash
awk -F ' +-' -v OFS='\n-' '{$1=$1} 1' file

-V
-am line+tgl
-am assert
-debug+all
-zdb
-fcs_assert off
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace a space followed by a dash by a newline followed by a dash.

```bash
sed 's/ -/\n-/g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option specifying the row separator `RS` to one or more spaces followed by `-`

Prepend a hyphen starting from the second row on, so that there has been at least one match for the row separator.

```
awk -v RS=" +-" '{print (NR==1 ? $0 : "-"$0)}' file
```

Output

```
-V
-am line+tgl
-am assert
-debug+all
-zdb
-fcs_assert off
```